# Java ByteBuffer compareTo not working with allocate but it's ok with wrap

Tags: java, scala, hex, bytebuffer

It seems that I found very strange behavior using java `ByteBuffer`. My purpose is to fill `ByteBuffer` and use `compareTo` method. I'm running on OpenJDK 64bit using Ubuntu. Code snippet is scala worksheet but in java class it behave the same.
This works fine:

```
import java.nio.{ByteOrder, ByteBuffer}
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex

val str1 = "FFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000"
val str2 = "FFFFFFFFFFFF00000000000000000000"

val bb1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(Hex.decodeHex(str1.toCharArray))
val bb2 = ByteBuffer.wrap(Hex.decodeHex(str2.toCharArray))
println(
  s"""
     |bb1 hex: ${new String(Hex.encodeHex(bb1.array()))}
     |bb2 hex: ${new String(Hex.encodeHex(bb2.array()))}
     |Comparing: bb1.compareTo(bb2): ${ bb1.compareTo(bb2)}
  """.stripMargin)
bb1 hex: fffffffffff000000000000000000000
bb2 hex: ffffffffffff00000000000000000000
Comparing: bb1.compareTo(bb2): -15
```

This doesn't work (and don't know why)

```
import java.nio.{ByteOrder, ByteBuffer}
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex

val str1 = "FFFFFFFFFFF000000000000000000000"
val str2 = "FFFFFFFFFFFF00000000000000000000"

val bb1 = ByteBuffer.allocate(16)
val bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(16)
bb1.put(Hex.decodeHex(str1.toCharArray))//Do the same like in wrap
bb2.put(Hex.decodeHex(str2.toCharArray))//Do the same like in wrap

println(
  s"""
     |bb1 hex: ${new String(Hex.encodeHex(bb1.array()))}
     |bb2 hex: ${new String(Hex.encodeHex(bb2.array()))}
     |Comparing: bb1.compareTo(bb2): ${ bb1.compareTo(bb2)}
  """.stripMargin)
bb1 hex: fffffffffff000000000000000000000
bb2 hex: ffffffffffff00000000000000000000
Comparing: bb1.compareTo(bb2): 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, this is another one of the java's "features", that sometimes make you want to spank the guy, who came up with it and thought it would be a good idea :)

`ByteBuffer` has the notion of a current position, so that when you call `put` twice, the contents of the second array is appended after the end of the first one. What's funny is that `compareTo` compares the contents of two buffers *starting at the respective current positions*. So, in your case, both sequences are empty, and it just returns 0.

Comment: But those arrays are two seperate variables and they operate on different buffers. Nevertheless you are right with `put` method and `compareTo`. The solution for that is set position to 0. `bb1.position(0)`

Comment: not sure I understand what you mean by "but" :) 
Perhaps, you are confused by my referring to calling `put` twice ... that was just to illustrate the utility of the current position thingy, not to imply that you call it twice on the same buffer.